# jQuery Datatables fnReloadAjax() callback

Tags: jquery, callback, datatables, synchronous

Any ideas how to incorporate a callback function into this code or alternatively make it synchronous?

Thanks!

```
eTable.fnReloadAjax();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested, use this instead fnReloadAjax(), it works!

```
function RefreshTable(tableId, urlData)
{
  $.getJSON(urlData, null, function( json )
  {
    table = $(tableId).dataTable();
    oSettings = table.fnSettings();

    table.fnClearTable(this);

    for (var i=0; i<json.aaData.length; i++)
    {
      table.oApi._fnAddData(oSettings, json.aaData[i]);
    }

    oSettings.aiDisplay = oSettings.aiDisplayMaster.slice();
    table.fnDraw();
  });
}

RefreshTable('#HelpdeskOverview', '/Helpdesk/ActiveCases/noacceptancetest');
```

More info can be found here:
http://www.meadow.se/wordpress/?p=536